# How to enlarge the Safari Web Inspector: Details sidebar?

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

I am using:
Safari Version: 11.0

and on accident had been able to enlarge the Details sidebar but now am not able to move past the

current setup: [image: ![personal-site just for example use]

I would like to know if there is a way to **increase the Details sidebar without increasing the Content browser?**

I recently noticed that increasing the Content browser allows for ability to increase the Details sidebar but I would like to only increase the size of the Details sidebar.

Link to old version of Safari, still correct labels: [Safari Inspector Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Do you mean the width, or the font size?

Comment: The width for the details pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, how the sidebar works is that you can only increase the size of the details section once the left side has reached a certain size threshold.

Other than popping the dev tools out into a new window (by hitting the top left detach button) or by using another browser without this limitation (like Chrome) then this will not be possible.